# When I open the Eclipse application I get this exit code error issue. How do I resolve this?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, codenameone

When I open the Eclipse application I get this exit code error issue. How do I resolve this?

[The exit code issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EODlC.png)

Thank you and help would be appreciated in resolving this error.=-)

Comment: You are using a 64 bit Eclipse with a 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflict with your version of eclipse and installed jvm, for repairing this issue just download eclipse for with same architecture as your jvm (if jvm is x32 eclipse must have x32, the same thing with x64) or specify Eclipse.ini
[Specifying jvm](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)

Comment: Where do I get the 64bit version of java

Comment: You can download x64 jvm here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html or just download eclipse x32 without downloading jvm

Comment: @user6889595 Did it clarify the situation?

Comment: Thankyou it solved the problem